# Css fixed postition in wordpress covers footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My Page is [link](http://salonshine.pl/_beta/?page_id=13). I wanna set navigation under footer. 
My custom css code, which i have set for footer, but footer is still covered.

```
#scroller {
padding: 5px;
background-color: white;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
_position: absolute;
-ie: expression(this.style.top=document.documentElement.clientHeight-this.offsetHeight+document.documentElement.scrollTop);
}
```

Have you got any idea? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nav bar has absolute position it is overlapping the footer.

You have to either place `nav menu div` below `footer div` without `position:absolute` or use padding bottom (`height of the nav menu+current padding which is 84+40=124px`) to footer.

```
.site-footer {
border-top: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
color: #999;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 40px 0 124px 0;
text-align: center;
}
```